# Will my Mac OS flashed RX 580 work with windows?

Tags: windows, mac, drivers, gpu

I am planning a new PC build and for a temporary card I plan to use a RX 580 that was flashed for a Mac a while back ago. Will it work with windows? or will I just get no output. Thank you!

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot flash the original firmware back on the card?

Comment: I'm borrowing it. I can't do that without the owners permission.